# Discrete Math Big O Notations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I'm studying for my discrete math class and I don't fully understand how to proof how a function is not a big O for certain questions. I understand that you have to assume that it is big O and proof by contradiction.

Please explain how you attacked these questions step by step.

1) $1$ is not $O(\frac{1}{x})$

2) $e^x$ is not $O(x^5)$

Comment: Use the definition of $O(\cdot)$.

Comment: For the second : $e^x$ grows faster for $x\rightarrow \infty$ than every function $x^n$ , $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: @flawr using the definition - f(x) <= c*g(x) - 1) seems to easy. If I do that, 1 <= c*1/x. Do I multiply to get rid of the denominator x?

Comment: @Peter Yeah I know but how do I proof that :S

Comment: You can use the taylor-series of $e^x$ to prove that or you can apply L'Hospital's rule multiple times until the polynomial becomes constant.

Comment: @Peter We aren't being taught L'Hospital's rule in this class. I'm looking at some other text books questions and they seem so easy but I just can't figure out how to proof these 2 practice questions.

Comment: If you cannot use the Taylor series either, I know no proof.

Comment: @Peter I'll look into these thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Suppose $1=O(1/x)$. Then there exists a constant $C$ such that for all large $x$, we have $1 \le C/x$. However, for all $x>C$ we have $C/x < 1$, a contradiction.

2) Suppose $e^x=O(x^5)$. Then there exists a constant $C$ such that for all large $x$ we have $e^x \le Cx^5$. However, $\frac{e^x}{x^5} \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, a contradiction. [As Peter suggests, use L'Hopital's rule multiple times, or expand the Taylor series for $e^x$.]